# Jenkins GUI only shown after waiting for 2 minutes

Tags: jenkins

My Jenkins version is Jenkins 1.508. Some googling around seemed to indicate that I needed a small change in my jenkins.xml (see for instance http://devophuman.blogspot.nl/2013/04/jenkins-is-going-wild.html), but that xml change did not help a lot in my case. Today I installed the monitoring plugin, and can see that jenkins needed 112,978 ms to respond to my request, where should I look for the culprit?

Comment: 1st, I suggest you update to the latest Jenkins available. We run 1.550 without any problems. 2nd, do you run it behind a web server like httpd or other? If so, check the logs.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend checking a couple different things.

1. Is the `jenkins` process pegged at **100% CPU or higher**? This could indicate that there are, for example, too many builds being kept around (`Jenkins` seems to have trouble with this; I usually keep no more than **25 builds per job** to help prevent performance issues from this). I've noticed the `Performance` plugin can also lead to intense CPU usage, especially when it is drawing the graphs (which `Jenkins` does not cache nor save to disk, so each page load they need to be recreated).
2. What does the `Jenkins` access log say? Does it quickly register your request but then sit there seemingly doing nothing? If this is the case and the CPU isn't pegged on the `jenkins` process, it may be a browser issue.

I found that pages  weren't loading even after 5+ minutes, but there
    was seemingly no `jenkins`-based load on the server, nor any serious load
    on the box elsewhere. I had been using `Firefox` to access the
    pages, and when I tried the same page in `Chrome`, it loaded
    instantly. I could then go back to `Firefox` and it again would not load.
    So there was something wrong at that point in time with the browser with respect to `Jenkins` (not sure quite what it was). So now I generally use `Chrome` to access
    `Jenkins` and haven't really noticed slow/non-loading pages since.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

To clean up old builds, I employ a two-phase process:

1. Navigate to the **jobs** directory of your `Jenkins` install and then into the **builds** directories of each job you want to clean up. From there simply delete the directories of the builds you no longer want (using whatever shell tools you prefer -- find, etc.) If too many builds is the issue, cleaning these up at the file system level should then allow `Jenkins` pages and views to load.
2. If the cleanup then allows you to load the pages for the jobs, you can then click the `Configure` action to change the config and select the option to keep a limited number of builds, setting it to a lower value, such as 25.

If the `jenkins` process isn't pegged at a high CPU number, it seems somewhat unlikely that it's the number of builds that are the issue, but it's probably worth a try. If you think you may want the build info back later, simply move them to a location outside the **jobs** folder hierarchy instead of deleting them and Jenkins won't know about them. You can always move it back later.

It's probably best to do the file-level moving with Jenkins stopped, and then reload it once the cleanup is done. It will then have far fewer builds to iterate over.

**Edit in response to follow-up comment from OP:**

Re: **point 1**, that definitely sounds like there might be an issue with the installation (cross-linked separate installs, or something like that).

Re: **point 2**: That will depend in part on how Jenkins was installed. i.e. is it running on Tomcat, or with standalone?

Re: **point 3**: This **really** sounds like you might have cross-linked installs. If you stopped Jenkins, the GUI really should no longer work.

Re: **point 4**: 11 seconds is certainly a huge improvement over 2 minutes. That definitely suggests that too many kept-builds was **one** problem, but the pages really should be pretty snappy to load on a relatively idle system, so it sounds like there may potentially be some other issues as well, particularly a cross-linked install of sorts.

Is there ever more than one **jenkins** process running? Is **Tomcat** involved?

**Edit in response to OP's follow-up comment:**

Given your comments about not recalling the details of the original installation, I think it may be best to simply install Jenkins from scratch using the self-contained (i.e. non-Tomcat) method, and then migrate your data from the old install as I mentioned previously, copying the whole jobs directory elsewhere first just in case.

This way you can be sure of the installation details and get to keep the data.

Comment: The server is not pegged at 100%, it's about 80% idle. Our team is always using Chrome, but I did not clean up any builds since the Jenkins installation took place. I find many logs in the Jenkins install directory, but no access log. The err.log is rather large, and shows many messages like 'could not load ...'. So I guess the first thing to do is: cleaning up some older builds. What is the recommended way to do this?

Comment: Added some info about how I go about cleaning up builds when the Web UI is wedged. Also, what was the reason it gave in the error logs for not being able to load the pages? Any error patterns?

Comment: 1) Log File, reason for 'could not load ...': Invalid directory name. 2) I'm still wondering where the access log might be ...
3) Stopped jenkins but gui still worked, killed the process instead of stopping the service. Don't know if this might be relevant for response times, but something seems to be wrong with my jenkins installation.
4) Cleanup: did exactly what you advised: manually removed all builds before 1/6/2014, and reconfigured the jobs. First remote gui access took 11 seconds. That's better then 2 minutes, but we'll have to see
how this evolves in the coming days.

Comment: Added add'l response to answer.

Comment: One problem is that I installed Jenkins about one year ago, and I forgot about the installation details. Another problem is that I have many tomcats running on that server, on different ports. The port 8080 of the jenkins GUI makes me think there is some relation to tomcat, but the jenkins service is started as D:\Programs\Jenkins\jenkins.exe, and the directory structure there is NOT a traditional tomcat one with logs, webapss (there is a 'war' instead) subdirectories. I only see the jenkins.exe in process explorer. There is too little log information to see what the gui is struggling with.

Comment: Added on to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience its related to Windows file system being really bad at handling folders with a lot of sub folders. Loading a View could take up to a minute.

We made our Jenkins Views fast again by reducing the default builds stored per job and delete the old builds as suggested by khampson.

I would expect a Jenkins running on Linux to be much better at handle big number of builds

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the problem for the original poster, but I hope it might help others who land here via a web search.  In our Jenkins’ case the massive UI slowdown turned out to be a network issue.  I’d moved the server to a temporary location during an office move, where the setting in Jenkins Location/Jenkins URL would fail.  Setting it temporarily to *hostname*.local returned page loading to normal.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading Jenkins to version 1.568, and cleaning up the job directories, the typical response time on a first call of the day is down to about 20 seconds. I think the 'first call of the day' is important here, because when I then go to another machine, the GUI renders immediately there. This might be related to the company proxy, caching mechanisms here and there, or the internal jenkins implementation, but I can live with the current situation.

Comment: Hi Erik, we have the same issue with the loading in the morning. We do not use proxies. So it is a jenkins issue afaik.

Answer (score 0):

We have implemented a quick and dirty work around. Just create a job in Jenkins which periodically invokes the following shell script:

```
wget http://localhost:8080/view/All/ -O /dev/null
```

This reduces the load times for all views (since Jenkins has to take the hit himself) for our users.

As stated in the comment the wget only loads the job view. In order to interate all jobs we are using the following curl script (Linux based host):

Jenkins 1.x;

```
for x in ` curl 'http://localhost:8080/api/xml?tree=jobs\[url\]' | sed 's/<url>/\n/g' |  sed 's/<\/url>//g' | sed 's/<job>//g'| sed 's/<job>//g' | sed 's/<\/job>//g' | grep http | sed 's/your.jenkins.host.domain/localhost:8080/' ` ; do curl "$x" -o /dev/null ;done
```

Jenkins 2.x;

```
for x in `  curl 'http://localhost:8080/api/xml?tree=jobs\[url\]' | sed 's/<url>/\n/g' |  sed 's/<\/url.*//g' | grep http | sed 's/your.jenkins.host.domain/localhost:8080/' ` ; do curl "$x" -o /dev/null ;done
```

You can of course to the same thing for views (http://localhost:8080/api/xml?tree=views[url])

Comment: sadly this is not working for folder plugin in jenkins. Since the projects are below the folders and therefore still not loaded

Comment: I have updated my post with a curl script used to fetch all jobs instead. The same method can be applied for jobs, view and all other types accessible through the API.

Comment: thank you for the update, tested the curl. My jenkins is prohibiting the access. Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Comment: You can provide access for the unauthenticated user to different resources under configure global security.  Which authentication plugin do you use?

Comment: using: "Jenkins’ own user database" with "Role-Based Strategy"
But allowing anonymous a access to a protected area makes no sense to me?!? Maybe since I could not find the proper place to check the permissions

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with multiple LTS Jenkins versions, running as a Windows service. Oddly enough, launching Chrome in incognito mode then browsing to the Jenkins URL has Jenkins loading significantly faster. It was taking about 1 minute to paint for multiple users, but in incognito mode it takes less than 5 seconds. I'm not sure why the cache is such an issue. Clearing the cache resolves the issue for a short time, but it starts again within a couple hours, so incognito mode is the way to go.